# Яка зменшувально-пестлива форма до слова "ковдра" (чим накривають ліжко/накриваються)?

Tags: вибір-слова, діалекти

В мене є варіант **"ковдерка"**, але друзі кажуть, що такого слова немає. Мені ж здається, що це слово є, можливо, діалектним (галицький діалект). Швидке ґуґління показує дуже незначну присутність цього слова на просторах Інтернету, всього-навсього декілька згадок у приватних оголошеннях, а також в деяких літературних перекладах:

> Сара натягнула на себе тоненьку **ковдерку**, – уявімо, що це чудесне,
>   м'яке ліжко, з шерстяними ковдрами й пухкими подушками ("Маленька принцеса"/ Бернет Френсіс Годґсон)

Є також інший варіант - **"ковдронька"**, який мені видається також можливим.

Подається також варіант **"ковдрочка"** [Словником української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kovdrochka)

Отже точніше питання - Чи варіант **"ковдерка"** можна вважати одним із допустимих в літературній мові (якщо виходити, наприклад, з чисто лінґвістичних правил формування зменшувально-пестливих форм)?

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE. Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання, що ви вже шукали і яких висновків вже дійшли. Почитайте про наші [критерії](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/240), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити своє питання або відповідь за допомогою посилання edit.

Comment: Дуже дякую, що виправили своє питання, тепер виглядає набагато краще. Ще раз вітаю на staxkexchange і сподіваюсь на плідну співпрацю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Перепрошую, що відповідь частково дублює інформацію із запитання — я просто писав відповідь на [цю версію запитання](/revisions/4998/2), але потім запитання було доповнене.</sub>

Такі варіанти є в словниках:

- **ко́вдрочка** (ж. р.) — [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/kovdrochka) (1970–1980), [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (2008) і [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42536&page=1343) (2010–…);
- **ко́вдронька** (ж. р.) — [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=209730&page=1343) (2010–…).

Такі варіанти, наскільки я можу судити, ще не включені в словники, але іноді вживаються в літературі:

- **ковдерка** (ж. р.):

  > Вони забрали дідусів кожух і мою ковдерку (Зiнаїда Тулуб, Людолови, 1935).
  >
  > Він одягнув досить притертого гумака, на нього накульбачив великий пакунок, де була одна зміна білизни, запасні черевики, одяг та невеличка ковдерка — дарунок матері. <…> Та ковдерка була єдиним і останнім подарунком матері. <…> Він знав, що не сьогодні, то завтра вона готова до нього прилетіти, ковдерку ще одну принести йому. <…> Чи кусок петльованика, чи сиру, чи чого іншого клалось само від себе в неї і старий, не дякуючи за дарунок і не сердячись за фіґля, м'ямляючи пожовклими устами, дибав собі на подвір'я з вошивою ковдеркою під пахвою (Улас Самчук, Кулак, 1935).
  >
  > Не можна утепления (солома, мата, сінничок, ковдерка і т. ін.) викидати, навпаки ще більше утпелюється, бо вітри і холодні ночі бжолам дуже шкодять ([Український пасічник, 1937](//books.google.com/books?id=UGhPAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)).
  >
  > Хлопці беруть це до відома, лягають мовчки, загортаються у свої тонкі ковдерки і сплять (Улас Самчук, Юність Василя Шеремети, 1946).
  >
  > <…> одбИт' — зфотографувати
  >   оддАт' дочкУ — видати заміж
  >   одрОстик, -а — зраз щепити
  >   од'ійАло, -а — ковдра; од'ійАл'це — ковдерка
  >   од'Іц'ц'а — одягнутися ([Наукові записки: Wissenschaftliche Mitteilungen, 1968](//books.google.com/books?id=1tJJAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)).
  >
  > А раненько, як мене збудить шелест в хаті, я зобачу маму, рожеву від морозу, вона сміється до мене і кидає мені на ковдерку букетики на дротах, карнети, малесенькі олівчики. <…> Іренка дістала грубі книжки і синю шапочку й рукавички, Ромко — столярське майстерство, Стефко — магічну ліхтарню, а я досить велику ляльку в ліжечку, а там є ковдерка і подущинка (Марія Струтинська, Далеке зблизька, 1975).
  >
  > Хлоп'я затиснуло під пахвою подушку, на плечі стара ковдерка (Портяк Василь, Мицьо і Вовчур, 1980 — [1](//books.google.com/books?id=oPpDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%22), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=bzpgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%22), [3](//books.google.com/books?id=VigYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)).
  >
  > Ковдерка в умовах воєнних мандрів геть пошарпалася, але мати її старанно залатала незадовго до своєї смерти (Юрій Шевельов, Я, мені, мене… (і довкруги), 1987).
  >
  > Мабуть він відчув мою постанову, бо тільки зробив якусь гримасу й, не розпитуючи більше, кинув у мій бік дитячу ковдерку, подушку і якусь пом'яту сорочку. <…> Загорнув я в ковдерку не від серця дані дари, вийшов із похиленою головою й тяжкими думками (Богдан Казанівський, Шляхом Леґенди, 2005).
  >
  > Славка не лягала спати, — вона сиділа у фотелі коло ліжечка і час від часу міняла ковдерку дитини, що була вся мокра від поту (Олекса Чинилук, Між Воєн, 2007).
  >
  > І уявімо, — Сара натягнула на себе тоненьку ковдерку, — уявімо, що це чудесне, м'яке ліжко, з шерстяними ковдрами й пухкими подушками (Френсіc Бернет, Маленька принцеса, 2013, переклад — Віта Левицька).
- **ковдринка** (ж. р.):

  > Ковдринку, що нею накривався, аби приберегти тепло, нагорнув тугіше на плечі, на груди (Іван Чендей, назва твору невідома, 1967 чи раніше — [1](//books.google.com/books?id=Dl3qAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%22), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=bGHnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%22)).
  >
  > Яся поставила візочок осторонь переїзду на осонні і нагнулася до Андрійка, який міцно спав, закутаний в теплу білу ковдринку (Михайло Клоков, Зелене й червоне, 1971).
  >
  > — Та й ми трошки розжилися, — похвалилась Катерина. — Думаю, буде і на ліжничок і на ковдринку, і на ряденце. А може й одіяльце вийде ([Лук'ян Карий, Крах, 1985](//archive.org/details/smoloskyp_20160708/page/n395)).
  >
  > Дитинка була оповита в стареньку сіру ковдринку ([Наталія Хаммоуда, Мереживо людських доль, 2018](//books.google.com/books?id=tsxJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR106&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)).
  >
  > Хотіла накупити полотна на пелюшки, і коцика, і ковдринку на зиму ([Наталія Хаммоуда, Звір, 2018](//books.google.com/books?id=sMxJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT138&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)).
- **ковдерце** (с. р.):

  > В мене тече річка з вишньового саду —
  >   Водица в кубочку, рушник на кілочку,
  >   Горілочка з перцем в ліжку під ковдерцем.
  >   Водицой умийся, рушничком утрися,
  >   Горілки нап'ємся, спати положимся ([Ой галка, галка — чужая подманка // Українські народні пісні в записах Зоріана Доленги-Ходаковського: з Галичини, Волині, Поділля, Придніпрянщини і Полісся, 1974](//books.google.com/books?id=_yAkAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC%22)).
  >
  > Витягла тоненькі рученята, звільнивши їх з ковдерця, й потяглася (Валерій Шевчук, Дiм на горi, 1967–1980).
- **ковдерко** (с. р.):

  > Гадав, що в дитячій уяві, можливо, своє ковдерко брав за волохатого ведмедика (Іван Липа, Мій ведмедик, 1903–1923).

Висновки: Слова *ковдрочка* і *ковдронька* вже зафіксовані словниками. Слова *ковдерка* і *ковдринка* вживаються рідко, але в літературі присутні (рідше за *ковдрочка*, але частіше за *ковдронька*) — я думаю, рано чи пізно словники їх зафіксують. Чи є *ковдерка* діалектним, чи просто рідковживаним — мені важко сказати.

<sub>Цитати взяті з [Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word=%22[%D0%BA%D0%9A]%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80.*%22]) та Google Книг.</sub>